# Load/deserialize matrices from MongoDB to pySpark, add new vector column

Tags: python, mongodb, serialization, pyspark

I'm studying Spark in order to use its ML module to build classifiers.

I've successfully used Pandas for this task, but amount of data has grown, and now they don't fit in RAM. I've also have a positive experience using Dask, but its machine learning libraries are not ready for production.

My data are stored in MongoDB and contain small images, serialized with `cPickle`.

Here is the code snipped for their creation:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pymongo
from bson.binary import Binary

records = []
for file_path in file_paths:
    for r in file(fn):
        normalized_image = np.random.rand(120, 40)
        this_result = {'file_name': os.path.basename(file_path),
                       'normalized_image' : Binary(cPickle.dumps(normalized_image, protocol=2)),
                        # other data 
                       }
        records.append(this_result)


client = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_CREDENTIALS)
db_name = 'database_name'
client.drop_database(db_name)
database = client[db_name]
collection = database['data_sample']
collection.insert_many(records)
```

I've understood from ML documentation that classifiers work with vectors and matrices, defined in `pyspark.ml.linalg` module.

I've managed to read data from the database to the Spark DataFrame using official MongoDB Spark connector.
However, they are still serialized:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.ml as ml

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("sparktest") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://mongo.server/database_name.data_sample") \
    .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load().drop('_id')
df.printSchema()


root
 |-- file_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- normalized_image: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- parea: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sns: double (nullable = true)
....
```

How do I deserialize them?

I also need to calculate histograms for each of these images and store them as a new column of the resulting data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to now, I've come to the following solution

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction

def deserialize_calc_histogram(ser_image):
    return ml.linalg.Vectors.dense(get_histogram(data=cPickle.loads(str(ser_image)), 
                               scale_factor=(4, 1.4)))

histo = UserDefinedFunction(deserialize_calc_histogram, ml.linalg.VectorUDT())
encode_boolean = UserDefinedFunction(lambda b: int(b), pyspark.sql.types.IntegerType())


df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load().\
             select(['bool_label', 'is_train', 'normalized_image'])

train = df.filter(df.is_train == True).\
        withColumn("norm_histogram", histo("normalized_image")).\
        withColumn("label", encode_boolean("bool_label")).\
        drop('normalized_image')

df.printSchema()
```

Output

```
root
 |-- label: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- is_train: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- normalized_image: binary (nullable = true)
```